# How does Naive Bayes assumption make segmentation less computationally intensive?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, linguistics

I was going through a video of Udacity's Intro to AI Class and I can't seem to wrap one idea around my head.

It is stated that for a string of length n 2<sup>n-1</sup> segmentations are possible. When we take the Naive Bayes assumption the best segmentation s<sup>*</sup> can be defined as the one that maximizes

product(P(w<sub>i</sub>))

It is possible to write the best same as:

s<sup>*</sup> = argmax<sub>s</sub> P(first_word) * s<sup>*</sup>(rest_of_words)

I understand why the above is True. The instructor said that due to the above equation we do not have to enumerate all 2<sup>n-1</sup> cases. I am not able to understand the reason for this.

I also understand that finding P(single_word) is simple than learning the same prob for n-grams and that would help computationally too.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are working with single words, we have to choose one word per time and not all their combination, thus reducing the search space. Consider the string:

"Iliketennis"

The string has 11 chars, thus 2^11=2048 cases. If we start looking at the most probable first word it could be:

"I", "Il", "Ili", "Ilik" and so on. 11 possible cases. Now that we have all the possible first words, we look for the most probable:

- P("I")=0.4,
- P("Il")=0.0001,
- P("Ili")=0.002,
- P("Ilik")=0.00003
- ...

and so on.

Finding out that the most probable is "I", we take it as the first word and now we can focus on the remaining 10 chars/cases:

"liketennis"

Repeating the same process you will have now 10 possible cases for the word, with probability:

- P("l")=0.05,
- P("lI")=0.0001,
- P("lik")=0.0002,
- P("lik")=0.00003
- P("like")=0.3
- ...

and so on.

So we pick "like". Now the search is repeated for the last 6 chars. Without writing again the process, "tennis" is picked up and no chars are left, so the segmentation is ended.

Since we have made an analysis word-wise, the possibilities we have considered are

11+10+6=27

much much less than spanning over the 2048 possible splits.

Comment: What happens in case we get the first word wrong. Consider "intheworld". The correct first word is "in". Suppose that as per our data P("i") > P("in"). I would guess that this greatly increases the number of cases as we have to backtrack?

Comment: More importantly how would we know that we should backtrack if we don't try every first word possible. This would be the same as trying everything. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @TarunKumar up to my knowledge, in the simplest approach and the one described by the exercise mentioned in the question, no backtracking strategy is provided. But still I do not think one needs to try everything: you could also apply naive bayes starting by identifying the last word and recursively on the preceeding chars. Done that you can compare the two solutions and see the best one (or even mix them). Notice that in your example, "intheworld" will be correctly splitted.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I did not exactly get what you mean by how we can compare solutions without trying all of them. It would help if you can give a concrete example.

Comment: Looking at the propabilities as I have described in the answer, starting from the beginning you will split: seq1 = I-n-the-world. Starting from the last word: world-the-in -> in-the-world=seq2. Obviously, since P('n') it is very low, you should have P(seq1)<P(seq2), so you pick the second split (obtained starting from the end) as the most probable one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a video by Mathematicalmonk,
this video: https://youtu.be/qX7n53NWYI4?t=9m43s

He explains that without conditional independence assumption (Naive Bayes), you need much more samples to estimate probabilities when you learn from data. But if you assume (even if it's incorrect) the independence between features, with less training data you can estimate the probability distribution.

Why? let's make it simple, without naive assumption, the probability of a 2-dimensional feature vector for a prediction `y` would be:

[image: without naive assumption]

By assuming only binary values for `x_1` and `x_2` features, you need to store these value per `y`, learnt from sample data:

```
P(x_1=0|y), P(x_1=1|y), P(x_2=0|x_1=0,y), P(x_2=0|x_1=1,y), P(x_2=1|x_1=0,y), P(x_2=1|x_1=1,y)
```

In another word, you need to store [image: 2^1+2^2] parameters. You can generalize it to d-dimensional binary feature vector:

[image: generalized without naive]

If you take the naive assumption and assume these features are independent, you will have this formula:

[image: naive assumption]

which means you only need to store these parameters per `y`, in order to predict all possible `X`:

```
P(x_1=0|y), P(x_1=1|y), P(x_2=0|y), P(x_2=1|y)
```

Or generalize it to:

[image: generalized with naive]